# Turn list of colon-delimited values into key=value pairs

Tags: text-processing

I need a bash or python script to read lines from text with these example lines :

```
1:2:3:4
4:3:2:1
```

And write them to new text file with this output:

```
A=1
B=2
C=3
D=4

A=4
B=3
C=2
D=1
```

Comment: could there be more than 4 values per line?

Comment: Thnx for response .. Yes could be

Comment: Great. It seems you know what you want. What have you tried so far? In what way didn't it work? Have you used https://shellcheck.net/ to pick up the more obvious errors? Please include your _formatted_ code [in the question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/445122/edit), explaining how you've tried to fix it and where you are stuck.

Comment: Well untill now i don't have any way i am looking for  a solution and i hope i can find it here

Comment: what if you had a number >=27? it should take which character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -F: '{ print "A=" $1 "\nB=" $2 "\nC=" $3 "\nD=" $4 "\n"; }' inputfile
```

or in bash

```
while IFS=: read -r a b c d rest; do
    printf 'A=%d\nB=%d\nC=%d\nD=%d\n\n' $a $b $c $d
done <inputfile
```

Comment: Hauke Laging you are the best you solved my probleb thank you man keep up

Answer (score 1):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{
         abc = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
         split(abc, letters, "")
     }
     {
         for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) print letters[i] "=" $i;
         print "" 
     }' FS=':' input.txt > newfile
```

---

`newfile` contents:

```
A=1
B=2
C=3
D=4

A=4
B=3
C=2
D=1
```

Comment: @MdAhmed, you have already accepted the answer, so your further questions are unneeded